# VBA: Creating charts dynamically, inconsistent output

Tags: vba, dynamic, charts

I think the issue is that I am using series and not overwriting them, but I am uncertain how to write code that will not store/delete a series after a chart has been generated.  Also, sometimes the charts generate as intended and other times they generate with both series and I can't discern a pattern in this behavior.  Basically looking to create a chart that will only use the columns I am passing in on that particular iteration of the loop rather than storing previously generated series.

The loop I'm using for generation:

```
'Loop for charts
Dim vGen As Variant
Dim vCurrent As Variant
vGen = Array("NOx EFL", "NOx EFH", "NOx UAF", "NOx_EFA") ', "NOx DAF")
For Each vCurrent In vGen
    Set Search = Cells.Find(What:=vCurrent, _
        After:=Cells(1, 1), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, _
        SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not Search Is Nothing Then
        Set Row_Start = Range(Search.Address).Offset(1, 0)
        Set Row_End = Range(Search.Address).Offset(row_count, 0)
        Set Data_Rng = Range(Row_Start, Row_End)
        Call make_chart(Fam_Rng, Data_Rng, Row_Start)
    End If
Next vCurrent
```

The chart creation function:

```
    Function make_chart(Fam, Data, Row_Start)
    Dim wbsheet As String
    sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    'Dim Char As Chart'
    Title_Str = Range("A2").Value & " " & Row_Start.Offset(-1, 0).Value

    Set Char = Charts.Add

    'With Worksheets("Charts").ChartObjects(Title_Str).Chart
    With Char
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Data
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Fam
        '.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = Title_Str
        .HasLegend = False
        .Name = Title_Str
    End With

    Worksheets(sheetName).Activate
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What range/data is selected at the time the chart is created can affect the outcome: I typically start by removing all series from any chart I create in code, before adding in the specific data I want to see.

Untested:

```
Sub make_chart(Fam, Data, Row_Start)
    Dim wbsheet As String
    sheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    Dim Char As Chart
    Title_Str = Range("A2").Value & " " & Row_Start.Offset(-1, 0).Value

    Set Char = Charts.Add
    With Char
        For Each s In .SeriesCollection 
            s.Delete 
        Next s 

        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries()
            .Values = Data
            .XValues = Fam
        End With

        '.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = Title_Str
        .HasLegend = False
        .Name = Title_Str
    End With

    Worksheets(sheetName).Activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

> other times they generate with both series and I can't discern a pattern in this behavior

Well, it actually depends on the current selection and how Excel tries to assess what series of data should be the chart's input, by looking to the current selection (and its neighborhood) in the currently active sheet.

- If the current selection is multiple, that selected data is the input data.
- If the current selection is a single cell, then the assessment of Excel as to what should be the input data is somewhat "greedy". it tries to look in the neighborhood for everything that looks like a data series. For example, if you are in a populated column and both the neighboring columns are populated, then (at least) 3 data series will be created. I say at least because the list can grow to as many neighboring columns are populated with data (the `region`).
- If the selection is single, in an *empty region*, the chart is created empty.

How can we start with an *empty* chart then? There are two methods:

1- clear the chart area immediately after the chart is created, using `ChartArea.Clear` (you could also iterate the series collection and delete each series individually but that's slow and we have better)

```
set cht = ThisWorkbooks.Charts.Add
cht.ChartArea.Clear
```

The only problem with this simple method is that a lot of CPU cycles might be lost if the current region has too many data columns, because too many series will be created for no use.

2- Set the selection to a single cell in an empty region before creating the chart. An obvious candidate is the bottom-right cell of the active sheet. Consider using the following custom function to create an empty chart

```
Public Function createEmptyChart() As Excel.Chart
   Dim oldSelection As Range
   With ActiveSheet
     Set oldSelection = ActiveCell ' <--- ActiveCell not Selection, the latter might be a shape!
     .Cells(.Rows.count, .Columns.count).Select
     Set createEmptyChart = ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add
     Application.Goto oldSelection  <-- needed only if restoring the
     createEmptyChart.Activate      <-- old selection really matters
  End With
End Function
```

p.s. a few things are tricky as you noticed, because you cannot simply rely on the `Selection` object, the current selection might be a shape. also, the function can be simplified if restoring the old selection doesn't matter.

p.s.2 Pleaaase dont use `Char` as the name of a variable :D